# How to override a static method when object type is initialized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

How can I have 2 functions share the same name with one being used as a `@staticmethod` while another if the object is initialized?

For example:

```
class Test (object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print("Called Static")
        pass
    
    def a(self):
        print("Called Init")
        Test.a()
        
t = Test()
t.a()  # This should print "Init" and then "Static"
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple functions with the same name in a class, the last function defined with the name is the only one that remains when the class is created all others are discarded

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  You'll just confuse those who have to read your code in the future.

Comment: implement the method in a subclass

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple functions with the same name, but you can try to differentiate between static and bounded calls by analyzing the arguments:
`t.a()` inserts the `self` argument, while `Test.a()` does not.

You can make a reasonable effort to detect that difference like so:

```py
class Test:
  def a(*arguments):
    if arguments and isinstance(arguments[0], Test):
      print("bounded call")
    else:
      print("static call")

Test.a() # static call
Test().a() # bounded call
```

However, note that this will fail for calls like

```py
t1, t2 = Test(), Test()

Test.a(t1, t2) # bounded call
```

because `Test.a(t1, t2)` is indistinguishable from `t1.a(t2)`.